# SSRS Report matching parent/child data incorrectly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I am having an odd issue with SSRS.  I built a report that works correctly when filtered down to a single part number in the underlying data set query.  When I take that filter off so that all data is displayed on the report, it does not work correctly.  In the latter instance, all of the child details display incorrectly (and randomly) under a single part number.

First case, when filtered to a single part number... all looks good and report works correctly:

[image: 1]

Second case, after taking filter off so that all data comes through... All of the part numbers show no detail, except randomly one part number will show all of the detail:

[image: 2]

I have been unable to figure out what is causing this confusing behavior... Any tips?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I just noticed that in the second case... all of the details show under whichever part number is last in the list...

Comment: Maybe a pic of your report's **Design** view might help figure out what the deal is.

Comment: I ended up rebuilding the report and it works fine now.  I think it was something whacky with the row groups... I spent too long trying to figure it out and just rebuilding seemed like the quicker option...

Comment: A lot of times, it's quicker to just start over than to figure out what's wrong.